# I need a React library for checking webpages update

Tags: reactjs

I am working on an project in react. I need api which would let me know if the URL given is updated (webpage is updated), libraries or API anything is fine

Answer (score 0):

This wont work in client side JavaScript, you will need a server side solution because most sites will not have the coors header set to allow you to check from the browser. Any server side language, Node, .NET etc can make a http request, save some stats and at a later date check if there have been updates but you wont be able to do it from the browser.